# Taking substring of one field and using value to field calculate or update cursor another in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a field that has values such as `DIMP 1234567 N. Eucla Ave/ W. Bonita Ave` or `DIMP Seg #1234567- Spinnaker Dr. Ventur` or `DIMP SEG 1234567 PYRITES AND ESMERALDA`.  I want to extract only the numerical values and update another field with those numerical values of the same row.   The field that has the numerical values is called `WORK_ORDER_REF` and the field that I want to update with the numerical value is `DIMP_SEGMENT`.  A variation of the code below updated the `DIMP_SEGMENT` field only with the first value of my list.

```
import arcpy

a = []
table = "table"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["WORK_ORDER_REF_DESCRIPTION", "DIMP_SEGMENT"]) as cursor:
     dimpsegs= [row[0] for row in cursor]
     for seg in dimpsegs:
        line = seg
        for word in line.split():
           try:
              a.append(int(word))
           except ValueError:
             pass
        for row in cursor:
            row[1] = a
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to find your number. `.split ()` won't work for numbers like `#1234567` because of the pound symbol. Also you only need to iterate your cursor once.

```
import re
import arcpy

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["WORK_ORDER_REF_DESCRIPTION", "DIMP_SEGMENT"]) as cursor:
    for desc, seg in cursor:
        seg = re.search (r"\d+", desc).group ()
        row = (desc, seg)
        cursor.updateRow (row)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `dimpsegs= [row[0] for row in cursor]` you are reaching the last row of your cursor, meaning that you need to create it again or use its [`reset()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm#M2_GUID-5CBF0F12-3B31-41AC-A525-65829523F692) method to resets the cursor back to the first row and update all the values in `DIMP_SEGMENT` field.

Try something like this:

```
import arcpy

table = "table"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["WORK_ORDER_REF_DESCRIPTION", "DIMP_SEGMENT"]) as cursor:
     dimpsegs= [row[0] for row in cursor]
     for row in cursor:
        a = [] # moved here as we need to clean it for each row!
        line = row[0]
        for word in line.split():
           try:
              a.append(int(word))
              row[1] = a
              cursor.updateRow(row) 
           except ValueError:
             pass
```